# Generalizar un metodo en una interfaz ¿Necesario?

Tags: java

Estoy realizando clases de **test** que contienen bastante codigo en común entre ellas dentro del mismo paquete , pero a la vez , no el suficiente ( a mi parecer ) como para meterlo en la clase padre , y me surge la idea de crear interfaces para generalizar dichos metodos.

- ¿Cual seria el metodo correcto ? Poniendo como ejemplo , que la
  ClasePadre extiende a mas de 50 Clases hijas , pero el metodo solo es
  comun en 2,3 o 4 de ellas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Mi idea era la generalizacion mediante interfaces , ¿Es correcta ?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Y en susodicho caso de que sea correcta la implementacion por interfaces ,¿ creariais dichos metodos estaticos o no ?

¡Un saludo y muchas gracias!

Comment: El planteamiento es muy ambigüo. ¿El mismo método en la clase padre y la interfaz? ¿La implementación (el código) también es común?

Comment: Ups! se ma ha olvidado quitarlo de las clases padres , la clase padre deberia estar vacia , ahora cuando pueda lo edito , gracias !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > Generalizar un metodo en una interfaz ¿Necesario?

Respuesta: **No**.

No necesitas usar interfaces. Puedes usar simplemente herencia. Por ejemplo, imagínate que tenemos una clase padre llamada **Vehículo** y sus clases hijas serán:

- Carro.
- Moto.
- Bicicleta.
- Patineta.

Estas clases hijas tendrán dos atributos comunes:

- Tipo de color.
- Número de ruedas.

Sin embargo, habrá un atributo llamado **Nombre del Motor** en la cual solo la tendrá dos clases hijas:

- Carro.
- Moto.

Entonces si llegáramos agregar el atributo `nomMotor` en la clase padre llamada `Vehiculo`, estaría mal, debido a que, una bicicleta o patineta no tienen motores y además, estaríamos desperdiciando memoria porque nunca usaríamos el atributo en esas clases hijas.

Una posible solución sería volver aplicar herencia, en la cual, tendríamos una clase hija llamada `VehiculoMotor` que heredaría los atributos de la clase padre `Vehiculo` y que a su vez se convierte en la clase padre de las clases `Carro` y `Motor`.

**¿Se puede hacer esto?**

**Si.** Porque un vehículo con motor sigue siendo un **vehículo**, por ende, es válido crear una clase denominada `VehiculoMotor`.

En este diagrama se visualizar mejor:
[image: img1]

Y el objetivo de hacer esto es poder agregar el atributo `nomMotor` en la clase padre `VehiculoMotor` y de este modo, las clases `Carro` y `Moto` heredarán de la clase `VehiculoMotor`. Así es como podrás reutilizar código.

En código quedaría así:

```java
abstract class Vehiculo
{
    private String color;
    private int numRuedas;

    public String getColor()
    {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color)
    {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public int getNumRuedas()
    {
        return numRuedas;
    }

    public void setNumRuedas(int numRuedas)
    {
        this.numRuedas = numRuedas;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Color: "+ color + "Numero de ruedas: "+ numRuedas + "\n";
    }
}

abstract class VehiculoMotor extends Vehiculo
{
    private String nomMotor;

    public String getNomMotor()
    {
        return nomMotor;
    }

    public void setNomMotor(String nomMotor)
    {
        this.nomMotor = nomMotor;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Tipo de Motor: " + nomMotor + super.toString();
    }
}

class Carro extends VehiculoMotor
{
    //code
}

class Moto extends VehiculoMotor
{
    //code
}

class Bicicleta extends Vehiculo
{
    //code
}

class Patineta extends Vehiculo
{
    //code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Entendiendo el concepto de la POO en Java podrás tomar la decisión si implementar interface o usar clase abstracta. 
Te recomiendo primero analizar si el método común corresponde a un comportamiento similar entre las clases hijas y si se  tiene relación con la clase padre entonces podemos usar herencia.

Para entender un poco mejor esto, te pondré un ejemplo sencillo.

Tenemos una clase padre que es Figura, y varias hijas que pueden ser Círculo, Cuadrado, Rectángulo.. etc.
Ahora la clase padre puede tener un método abstracto llamado obtenerArea  este método es común entre las clases hijas, solo que cada figura calcula el área de una manera diferente.

```
public abstract class Figura {

   public abstract float obtenerArea(); // este método es abstracto.

}
```

Tendremos que sobre escribir en cada clase el método para poder darle una función 
Ejemplo:

```
public class Cuadrado extends Figura{

  @override
   public float obtenerArea(){
         int ladoA=4;
         int ladoB = 4;
          return ladoA * ladoB;
   }

}

 public class Rectangulo  extends Figura{
  @override
   public float obtenerArea(){
         int base= 4;
         int altura= 2;
          return base * altura;
   }
}
```

También es válido usar interface y hay que entender bien el concepto pues te dejo un link para que sigas revisando.

https://codigofacilito.com/articulos/clases-abstractas-interfaces-java

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario Omar ! Te explico , el metodo en el que estoy dudando seria algo mas como un obtenerColor , un metodo , que es indistinto al tipo de figura , pero el problema radica en que el padre tiene muchos hijos figuras , los cuales la mayoria carecen de color , entonces no se cual seria la manera correcta de implementar ese obtenerColor , si en la clase padre a pesar de que lo usen solo un par de sus hijos , o extraerlo a una interfaz o una clase abstracta . ¡Gracias!